# What happens when I drop support for iOS 6?

Tags: ios, app-store

If I release an update to my app dropping iOS 6 support and adding iOS 7 compatibility, what will happen to users on iOS 6:

1. Will they see the update in the app store?
2. Will new users on iOS 6 simply download the last compatible version of the app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, but not able to update the app.
2. No. The new users, who haven't purchased your app yet, can't download it directly. But if they really want it, they can purchase it on an iOS7 device then download it in iOS6. In this way they will get a prompt of `download the app of its last compatible version`.

Comment: i guess they could also purchase it on iTunes running on a PC/Mac. No need for a new device.